# emaxima on beamer

Tags: beamer, emacs, maxima

I started using the `emaxima` package on emacs recently.

It provides me with `maxima` and `maximasession` environments which work perfectly fine in a latex "article" class document.
But while using it on beamer, I am facing issues with the `maximasession` environment. The error thrown goes like,
`ERROR: File ended while scanning use of \dom@ximatexsessionverbatim.`

Do let me know how I could fix this issue.

Adding an example :-
This works

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{beamer}

\usepackage[lines]{emaxima}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{maxima}
    diff(sin(x^2),x);
\maximaoutput*
\m  2\,x\,\cos x^2 \\
\end{maxima}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But this does not

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{beamer}

\usepackage[lines]{emaxima}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{maximasession}
    diff(sin(x^2),x);
\maximaoutput*
\i4.  diff(sin(x^2),x); \\
\o4.  2\,x\,\cos x^2 \\
\end{maximasession}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The preamble of the tex output :

```
Running `LaTeX' on `beamermaxima' with ``pdflatex  -file-line-error   -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" beamermaxima.tex''
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 1
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
```

The error message:

```
Runaway argument?
 diff(sin(x^2),x); \\ \o 4. 2\,x\,\cos x^2 \\ \end {maximasession} \end \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \dom@ximatexsessionverbatim.
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: my bad - I've added one through an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `fragile` option for the frame environment:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
...
\end{frame}
```

This is also needed for frames with `verbatim` environments as well as when using `Sweave` for `R` code chunks embedded in frames (both the `maximasession` environment as well as the `Schunk` environment produced by `Sweave` internally use `verbatim`!).

So the full working example should be

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[lines]{emaxima}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{maximasession}
  diff(sin(x^2),x);
\maximaoutput*
  \i4.  diff(sin(x^2),x); \\
  \o4.  2\,x\,\cos x^2 \\
\end{maximasession}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I had to remove the `[pdftex]` option from the `beamer` document class on my LaTeX installation (TeX Live 2015.2016032 on Mint 18.1), otherwise I got an option clash for the `color` package when comiling with `pdflatex`, it also occurs on my MacBoook with MacTeX 2015. This holds for both of your examples, the working and the non working one.

Comment: I agree that this is probably the problem. Still, it's better if you can add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) (i.e. complete compliable code), to show that you have actually solved it./